# Nuxt2 Plugin: Set cookie and redirect

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I found out that in Nuxt plugin if you set cookie with universal-cookies-nuxt it's not set immiedietly but it goes to queue.

If anywhere in your plugin you have `redirect()` function executed from Nuxt context it will close the request and cookies won't be set.

I found this info in github issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13685

They even provided some solution but it's using nuxt3 composables which I don't have available in nuxt2.

I tried to get same solution in my nuxt2 plugin like this:

```
import { serialize } from "cookie-es";
import { appendHeader } from "h3";

export default async function ({ req }: Context) {
  appendHeader(req, "Set-Cookie", serialize("111-test-2", "someValue"));

  if (route.query.code) {
    res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/" }).end();
  }
```

but `req` is definetly not what they expect to get in this `appendHeader` function:

[image: alt]

How to force this nuxt2 plugin to create a cookie before it will execute `redirect("/")`?